# Bypass Hcaptcha capmonster_python

Tags: python, discord

When creating a task to execute Hcapcha, an error occurs.

```
capmonster = HCaptchaTask(self.config["capmonster_key"])
task_id = capmonster.create_task("https://discord.com/register", "4c672d35-0701-42b2-88c3-78380b0db560")
captcha_token = capmonster.join_task_result(task_id)["gRecaptchaResponse"]
print(f'{self.lcaptcha}{self.green} Captcha Passed!  ' + captcha_token[:15])
```

```
'HCaptchaTask' object has no attribute 'create_task'
```

Answer (score 0):

#### That means there is no such method in HCaptchaTask

Can you show the documentation that made you think there *was* such a method?

Comment: https://capmonster-python.alperenn.com/usage/solve-hcaptcha